# Kubernetes using service cluster IP and port as environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a backend service on cluster IP 10.101.71.17 and port 26379. I have a frontend deployment where I intend to pass this service IP as an environment variable.

**frontend-deployment.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: frontend
    spec:

      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: localhost:5000/frontend
        command: [ "/usr/local/bin/node"]
        args: [ "./index.js" ]
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        - name: API_URL
          value: BACKEND_HTTP_SERVICE_HOST // Here
        - name: BASIC_AUTH
          value: "true"
        - name: SECURE
          value: "true"
        - name: PORT
          value: "443"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8079
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
---
```

I can get all the environment variables inside the pod but I am not sure what's the proper way of assigning it to the environment variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in your front end application your referring your back-end service in `API_URL` environment variable.

If this is the case just replace `BACKEND_HTTP_SERVICE_HOST` with `10.101.71.17:26379`

```
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        - name: API_URL
          value: 10.101.71.17:26379 
        - name: BASIC_AUTH
          value: "true"
        - name: SECURE
          value: "true"
        - name: PORT
          value: "443"
```

your should consider using the DNS name for services.

Comment: Well since I wanted a dynamic way, I used `$(BACKEND_HTTP_SERVICE_HOST)`. Can you share some example or point me in the direction for how I can use DNS name as a value?

Comment: if your running your back-end pods in the same cluster, create service named `backend`. then from our front end service you can refer it like this. `backend.default.svc.cluster.local` you can look at this page for details. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/